# How to make Sphinx resolve URL links from e.g. /about-manual to /about-manual.html

Tags: url-routing, python-sphinx

I'm creating a Sphinx documentation and I struggle to identify the "proper" way to set up the structure and links.

---

**STRUCTURE 1#**

Currently, my structure looks as below:

```
index.rst
   about-manual/index.rst
```

Inside my root `index.rst`, the toctree is as below:

```
===========================
Contents
===========================

.. toctree::

   about-manual/index
```

This results in the below links:

```
https://example.com/docs/             --> Content of index.rst
https://example.com/docs/about-manual --> Content of about-manual/index.rst
```

- This works as intended in terms of link resolution
- However, I'm unsure if it's the "proper" way of setting up my Sphinx structure

---

**STRUCTURE 2#**

```
index.rst
about-manual.rst
```

Inside my root `index.rst`, the toctree is as below:

```
===========================
Contents
===========================

.. toctree::

   about-manual
```

This results in the below links:

```
https://example.com/docs/                  --> Content of index.rst
https://example.com/docs/about-manual      --> ERROR
https://example.com/docs/about-manual.html --> Content of about-manual.rst
```

- This results in a more compact/simple Sphinx structure
- However, if a user enters an URL without explicit `.html` at the end, the link is broken

Am I missing a basic configuration setting in Sphinx in order to make the link resolution work as per my expectation with 'STRUCTURE 2#' - without having to add the explicit `.html` at the end?

And is it possible to avoid having the Sphinx documentation explicitly resolve to the `index.html` at the end of an URL path? It does this as expected on the root index, but in 'STRUCTURE 1#' all sub pages explicitly show the `index.html` at the end.

I've looked at `html_file_suffix` and `html_link_suffix`, but I've not been able to make these work for my purpose either.

Comment: You can configure your web server to redirect requests for files (those things lacking a trailing slash) to `<path>.html` or rewrite URLs to the same. Another option would be to put each file into its own directory named according to the file's purpose, and name it `index.rst`, so that its filename would resolve to an `index.html`, but that's kind of nuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this by using `sphinx-build -b dirhtml` instead of `sphinx-build -b html` (as proposed by Jesse Tan from the `sphinx_rtd_theme` team) - for details see [this link](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/builders/index.html#sphinx.builders.dirhtml.DirectoryHTMLBuilder).

It basically lets me use the approach in 'STRUCTURE 2#', but it builds the output with an `index.html` files structured in folders named as per the `.rst` files.

Importantly, the internal links are also updated to not include the `index.html` part.